# Is there anything like ISerializable that works for XMLSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I've got a class which implements it's own (de)serialization via XLINQ, and I'd
like to have clients of my class which attempt to XMLSerialze my class to have
my XLINQ method called instead.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IXmlSerializable has methods that you can implement that XmlSerializer will use instead of its own approach.

Edit: No idea if this applies to XLINQ or not, but I don't really see why not.

Comment: Doh! I fell like an idiot now. I HATE what they did with MSDN. Instead of a nice tree which probably would have found this on my own it's freaking broken. Anyway, thank you very much :)